# an objective-c category in same file exposed to outside world

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have seen a class which implements a catagory on itself. The code is as follow:

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface BPTopTabBarViewController : UIViewController

@end

@interface UIViewController (BPTopTabBarViewController)
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BPTopTabBarViewController *topTabBarViewController;
@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "BPTopTabBarViewController.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>
@implementation UIViewController (BPTopTabBarViewController)
- (BPTopTabBarViewController *)topTabBarViewController
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, BPTopTabBarViewControllerKey);
}

- (void)setTopTabBarViewController:(BPTopTabBarViewController *)topTabBarViewController
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, BPTopTabBarViewControllerKey, topTabBarViewController, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}
@end

@interface BPTopTabBarViewController () {
}

@end

@implementation BPTopTabBarViewController
...
@end
```

My Questions are:

1. What is the point of introducing a getter and setter on itself with a category of UIViewController? According to me only the class of BPTopTabBarViewController or the subclass of it can see the category because there is no category header(#import "UIViewController + BPTopTabBarViewController") declared in .h file.
2. I can see UINavigationController also have some structure like this:

   @interface UIViewController (UINavigationControllerItem)

Here we can always call a class of UIViewController or its subclass self.navigationController, how is the category exposed to UIViewController when it is written in UINavigationController class?
I also don't see the category header in UINavigationController.h file:

```
//  Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import <UIKit/UIViewController.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKitDefines.h>
#import <UIKit/UIInterface.h>
#import <UIKit/UIGeometry.h>
#import <UIKit/UIPanGestureRecognizer.h>
#import <UIKit/UITapGestureRecognizer.h>
```

3. If I want to expose the category to specific UIViewController class, what should I do?
4. If I want to expose the category globally, should I put #import "BPTopTabBarViewController.h" into project-Prefix.pch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm struggling to figure out where you've gotten your information from because most of it seems to be from inaccurate sources since the questions don't make much sense.  The point of the category is the be able to call this new method on **any** `UIViewController` or subclass thereof, even without access to its source code.

For example:

```
UIViewController *foo = [UIViewController new];
BPTopTabBarViewController *bar = foo.topTabBarViewController: //This will compile now
```

Part of the misunderstanding you may be having is what actually comes inside the parenthesis of a category.  This is *not* the name of anything in particular, it is just an identifier.  When you make a category, the class it gets added to is the class **outside** the parenthesis.

`UIViewController (BPTopTabBarViewController)` means a category named "BPTopTabBarViewController" which will affect `UIViewController`.

All you need to do to use it is `#import "BPTopTabBarViewController.h"` wherever you want to use it, or in your .pch file if you want to use it everywhere.

Comment: It seems that you answer my 3th and 4th questions. But as I know, if I want to apply a separated category B into effect (not in the same class files)in Class A, I should import the header like #import "UIViewController + B.h" in the .h file of Class A, why can I use the category when no #import "UIViewController + B.h" is declared? the category is just introduced along with A.h is imported?

Comment: I have tried, Yes, #import "BPTopTabBarViewController.h" works, thanks.

Comment: There is no need for importing a header like that (UIViewController + B.h) unless you actually **have** a header like that.  It's just a common convention people use when they have a filename with *only* a category in it.  I answered every question in here, whether you realize it or not.  The first few paragraphs are about #1 and 2

Answer (score 1):

Answers

1. This will make UIViewController Class and its subclass have the ability to call the setter and getter on a property of topTabBarViewController.
2. The same as 1.
3. Just import BPTopTabBarViewController.h to .m or .h.
4. Just include BPTopTabBarViewController.h in Prefix.pch file.